# The times of execution of this code

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series

```
int C = 0
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        for (int k = 0; k < N; k++)
            C++
```

Why this code is executed N(N - 1)(N - 2) / 6 times?

Comment: I think this is executed $n^3$ times. Correct me with reasoning, if I am wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For each loop the code is executed $n$ times.
>
> So, by multiplication principle the entire code is executed $n\cdot n\cdot n=n^3$ times.

---

However, the following nested loop code is executed $\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{6}$ times:

```
int C = 0
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        for (int k = 0; k < j; k++)
            C++
```

**Why?**

We may write this loop in summation form as:-

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^i \sum_{k=1}^j 1 
=\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^i j 
=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{i(i+1)}{2} 
=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{i^2}{2}+\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{i}{2} 
=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{12}+\frac{n(n+1)}{4}
\end{align}$$
$$ \qquad =\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{6} $$

---

**Note:** If we change the above code as follows, it is executed $\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{6}$ times. Proof is along the same lines as the previous and is left as an exercise to the reader.

```
int C = 0
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    for (int j = 1; j < i; j++)
        for (int k = 1; k < j; k++)
            C++
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It helps a lot!